# Postfix header_checks remove headers

Tags: email, ubuntu, postfix-mta

First of all I'm running lamp ubuntu 14.04 with dovecot and postfix for mailing.
I'm quite unexperienced if it comes to setting up a mail server.

I'm reaching a score of 5.1 / 10 and my mail does arrive on my gmail account, but not to my hotmail email. Here are the biggest problems reported by mail-tester
[image: Mail problems according to mail-tester]

The  mail will mainly be newsletter kind of things so the html problems I suppose should be fixed if I actually send a properly formatted html mail instead of some plain text lorem ipsum. Would be great if there's a solution for that as well, but it's not my biggest concern.

I'm using the header_checks in postfix trying to remove the X-MSMail-Priority, but without success. I can't find anything else besides the header checks method. Here's the line I'm using that I thought should remove X-MSMail-Priority

```
/^X-MSMail-Priority:/                   IGNORE
```

Please say so if I've forgotten something important or something is unclear. I'll update my question as quickly as possible

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you spelled the header correctly, it's case sensetive.
I'm assuming you have a file named `/etc/postfix/header_checks`,Check your `main.cf` file for the following:

```
mime_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

Restart postfix service and test the configuration.

Comment: try `pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks` instead of `regexp`